# Retrieve value returned from a function in Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I want to create a chart in Angular using chart.js and ng2chart. I have created a function to calculate a value I want to pass to my chart, but I can't do that as shown in the below code, since I would use the property 'online' before its initialization. What is another way I could pass the value returned from the `onlineNumber()` function to my `doughnutChartData`? This is the function:

```js
online: number;
term: number;
doughnutChartData = [this.online, this.term];

onlineNumber() : number {
    this.memberService.onlineUsers().subscribe((number: number) => {
      this.online = number;
    })
    return this.online;
  }

userNumber() {
     this.memberService.userNumber().subscribe((number: number) => {
      this.term = number;
    })
  }
```

The html:

```
 <div style=" margin-top: -6%; margin-left:15%; width: 50%;">
                                <canvas baseChart 
                                [data]="doughnutChartData"
                                [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                                [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
                                ></canvas>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a full working example?

My guess would be to initialize doughnutChartData inside the subscribe:

```
online: number;
doughnutChartData;

onlineNumber() : number {
  this.memberService.onlineUsers().subscribe((number: number) => {
    this.online = number;
    doughnutChartData = [this.online, 9];
  });
  return this.online;
}
```

Updated answer: add another method to initializeDoughnutChartData and use it inside userNumber and onlineNumber:

```
initializeDoughnutChartData() {
    if (this.online != undefined && this.term != undefined) {
        this.doughnutChartData = [this.online, this.term];
    }
}
```

Call this method inside userNumber and onlineNumber:

```
onlineNumber() : number {
    this.memberService.onlineUsers().subscribe((number: number) => {
      this.online = number;
      this.initializeDoughnutChartData();
    })
    return this.online;
}

userNumber() {
    this.memberService.userNumber().subscribe((number: number) => {
      this.term = number;
      this.initializeDoughnutChartData();
    })
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Your answer works if the second value was hardcoded, but I intended to send two values from two different functions. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Thanks! This works just fine, the array is filled with the correct values, but now I'm getting an error in the console and my chart is not displayed: `data or datasets field are required to render chart doughnut`. Why is that?

Comment: When the component is loaded doughnutChartData is undefined. That could be the reason for the error.

Maybe adding *ngIf="doughnutChartData" to your div (or the canvas) will help:


<div *ngIf="doughnutChartData" style=" margin-top: -6%; margin-left:15%; width: 50%;">
                                <canvas baseChart 
                                [data]="doughnutChartData"
                                [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                                [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
                                ></canvas>
     </div>